# D8 - How to create a view to show content with a field that is a User Reference to currently logged in user only

Tags: 8, entities, views

In Drupal 8, I have a content type `Medical Records` that has a field that is an Entity Reference to `Users`. I want to create a View which will display `Medical Records` with that field for the currently logged in user.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

you have to create a contextual filter, which will take current user as default value, you can find nice explanation and screenshots here:

http://redcrackle.com/blog/adding-contextual-filter-view-drupal-8

Just filter on **Content: your field name** instead of **Content: Authored by**

Comment: Though true and a nice tutorial, please include the essential part of the post in your answer, in case the link goes down. It is missing the crucial part that you should choose to provide a default value and set it to the ID of the current user.